# 2D Player Shaking When Platforms Move Up and Down?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision, rigid-bodies

For some reason, my player character shakes up and down when the platform moves up and down, which prevents the player from jumping because the player is not grounded. I tried several things including adding a kinematic rigidbody to the platform and trying to make the player a child of the platform after landing on the platform but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 posA;

    private Vector3 posB;

    private Vector3 nexPos;

    public GameObject Player;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform childTransform;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform transformB;

    void Start()
    {
        posB = childTransform.localPosition;
        posB = transformB.localPosition;
        nexPos = posB;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            collision.collider.transform.SetParent(transform);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            collision.collider.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        childTransform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(childTransform.localPosition, nexPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector3.Distance(childTransform.localPosition,nexPos) <= 0.1)
        {
            ChangeDestination();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeDestination()
    {
        nexPos = nexPos != posA ? posA : posB;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried "parenting" the player to the platform?

Answer (score 0):

Move(); should be executed in lateupdate, because otherwise you will set the position of the player and later the physics system will update it, causing stuttering.

Another solution would be raycasting straight down and placing your GameObject on the collision point (plus some kind of offset)